# Adding on update/on delete option to already existing column

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm stuck with MySQL query. I have 2 tables in my DB:
1 device
2 task

They are in relation 1 to 1. I have column "device_id" in task table and "task_id" in device table. I would like to make whole task's row deleted when I delete device row with given id_task.
Furthermore I would like to set id_task to null once I delete task row with given id_device. I'm pretty sure there's a possibility with ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN statemets but I'm getting #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax for like 30 minutes already.
Any suggestions?
btw, I've got some phpmyadmin but can't find those options, probably not available from ui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use foreign keys (assuming you are using innodb):

```
ALTER TABLE device
    ADD FOREIGN KEY
    (task_id)
    REFERENCES task (task_id)
    ON DELETE SET NULL

ALTER TABLE task
    ADD FOREIGN KEY
    (device_id)
    REFERENCES device (device_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
```

See here for a detailed description:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Yea, but I already have ForeignKeys set + my database is kind of full. So I want to just change option from curret to mentioned above. Don't want to create new columns

Comment: You cannot modify a foreign key constraint - you would have to drop it and re-add it.